# What defines structural equality?

Tags: functional-programming, mit-scheme, structural-equality

In terms of structural equality,

Why would `(equal? (list 'a 'b))` evaluate to true but `(equal? (list 2 'b) '(2 'b))` evaulates to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'(2 'b)` is equivalent to `(list 2 (list 'quote 'b))` - a list whose first element is a number and whose second element is another list.

It does not compare equal to `(list 2 'b)` because `(list 2 'b)`'s second element is a symbol and symbols are not considered equal to lists.